# Sum of factorials / binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I came across this identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!(n+1)!}{(n-k)!(n+k+1)!}(2k+1) = n+1. $$
This shows up quite undirectly when considering spherical harmonics, I would be interested in a direct argument.

More importantly, suppose $$A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \Big(\frac{n!(n+1)!}{(n-k)!(n+k+1)!}\Big)^2(2k+1) \qquad \text{and} \qquad B_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \Big(\frac{n!(n+1)!}{(n-k)!(n+k+1)!}\Big)^2(2k+1)^2.$$ Do we have $\frac{B_n}{A_n}\to \infty$ ?

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies that $B_n\ge n+1$, using the above identity. I am not sure whether $A_n$ diverges or not. The factorial quotient gets very small as $k$ approaches $n$.

**Edit:** I have accepted Claude's answer for the idea of using hypergeometric functions and their values, however I still welcome references for more details about these values, or alternative proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, if you compute the first $A_n$ and $B_n$ you should see that they are not of the same degree of magnitude at all.

Let

$$ a_n=\Bigg(\frac{n!(n+1)!}{(n-k)!(n+k+1)!}\Bigg)^2(2k+1)$$
$$ b_n=\Bigg(\frac{n!(n+1)!}{(n-k)!(n+k+1)!}\Bigg)^2(2k+1)^2$$ and consider
$$A_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_n\, x^n \qquad \text{and} \qquad B_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n b_n\, x^n$$ Both are given in terms of hypergeometric function.

$$A_n(1)= \frac{(n+1)^2}{2 n+1}$$
$$B_n(1)=\pi (n+1) \frac{ \Gamma (n+2)\,\, \Gamma \left(2
   n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2^{2 n+1}\,\,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \,\,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$

Asymptotically, using Stirling approximation and Taylor series,
$$R_n=\frac{B_n(1)}{A_n(1)}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}} \left(1+\frac{3}{16 n}+\frac{9}{512 n^2}+\frac{71}{8192
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$ which is very accurate.

For example, using $n=10$, the exact  result is
$$R_{10}=\frac{240990435}{59676188}=4.038301$$ while the approximation gives
$$\frac{8347111 }{1638400}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{5}}=\color{red}{4.0383}71$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have edited the question (I meant B_n/A_n \to infinity of course, not zero). Could you please elaborate how you found A_n(1) and B_n(1) ? Are there reference table values or something about them?

Comment: @Lonewolf. When I see factorials in denominators, I first thing about hypergeometric functions. This is why I introduced the $x^k$. Then, they are (more or less) "simple" to evaluate.

Comment: I am not quite familiar with these. I've tried to use them If I'm not mistaken, $A_n = 2 ( _3F_2(-n,-n,2;n+2,n+2,1)) - _3F_2(-n,-n,1;n+2,n+2,1)$ and $B_n = 4( _4F_3(-n,-n,2,2;n+2,n+2,1,1)) - 4( _3F_2(-n,-n,2;n+2,n+2,1)) + _3F_2(-n,-n,1;n+2,n+2,1)$. If that's correct, how did you find the values? I've checked on wikipedia, he computes some values for the more standard $_2F_1$. If you have a reference for the values or include more details in the solution, I'd be grateful, thank you.